# Need to move curser to a particular text box if another text box is already filled

Tags: java, swing

I have 2 text boxes as First Name and Last Name. When loading the screen the first name is already populated.

But the curser sets at the end of the first name text box. I need to move the curser to the last name text box if the first name is already given.

Here is what I have tried.

```
if (getContextGUI("FIRST_NAME").getValue().toString().length() > 0) {
            final ContextGUI lastName = getContextGUI("LAST_NAME");
            TextFieldContextGUI contextGUI = (TextFieldContextGUI) lastName;
            Component component = contextGUI.getComponent();
            JTextField jTextField = (JTextField) component; 
            int caterPosition = jTextField.getCaretPosition();
            jTextField.setText("");
            jTextField.requestFocus();
            jTextField.setCaretPosition(caterPosition);
}
```

Appreciate anyones help on this.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: If won't solve your problem but don't use requestFocust(). If you read the API it will tell you the method to use is `requestFocusInWindow()`. And when you post your [mre] use standard JDK classes. Your custom "TextFieldContextGUI class is not needed to demonstrate a focus issue.